# get coordinate (longitude and latitude) using google API in Python

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps

If I have address dataframe as follows:

```
id                Address                        Latitude       Longitude 
01   Via Benedetto Croce 112, Rome, Italy          
02   Via Aristide Leonori 46, Rome, Italy
03   Viale Marconi 197, Rome, Italy
```

How can i get their coordinates (longitude and latitude) using google API in Python? Thanks.

```
id                Address                        Latitude       Longitude 
01   Via Benedetto Croce 112, Rome, Italy       41.8423561    12.48535240000001
02   Via Aristide Leonori 46, Rome, Italy       41.8487061    12.488554900000054       
03   Viale Marconi 197, Rome, Italy             41.8567032    12.465537500002210
```

Here is what i find from Python client library for Google Maps API Web Services, but it fails with: raise googlemaps.exceptions.Timeout()

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

```
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='googlemap ak')
# Geocoding an address
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('Via Benedetto Croce 112, Rome, Italy')
print(geocode_result)
```

Comment: Have you researched this at all and looked at the Google API examples?

Comment: I don't think it's about pandas or numpy. Probably removing those tags is better.

Comment: I update my questions. Maybe numpy not, but pandas yes since it deal with an excel file or dataframe.

Comment: have you tried Nominatim? that doesnt need anykey

Comment: thanks, it will get OSM coordinates, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It uses Nominatim.

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
data = [
        {'Id':'01', 'Address': "Via Benedetto Croce 112, Rome, Italy", 'Latitude': None, 'Longitude' :None},
        {'Id':'02', 'Address': "Via Aristide Leonori 46, Rome, Italy", 'Latitude': None, 'Longitude' :None},
        {'Id':'03', 'Address': "Viale Marconi 197, Rome, Italy", 'Latitude': None, 'Longitude' :None}
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['city_coord']  = df['Address'].apply(geolocator.geocode)
df['Latitude'] = df['city_coord'].apply(lambda x: (x.latitude))
df['Longitude'] = df['city_coord'].apply(lambda x: (x.longitude))
print(df[['Address',  'Id',   'Latitude','Longitude']])
```

[image]